# How do I complete parentheses in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: kotlin

I want a way to complete the brackets like it is in pycharm and put the cursor between the brackets

```
kotlin
print("|")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "complete the brackets"? Can you show some sample inputs and outputs of what you want to do?

Comment: I am creating a CodeEditor application and I want when the user types, for example, the word print, the parentheses will be completed automatically.

Comment: Please show what you have done so far

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.